# auto-activate venv everytime i open VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I understand how to auto-activate venv (python) everytime I open new terminal in VScode (using Python: Select Interpreter)

but i can't find a way to auto-activate venv in terminal everytime i restart VScode. It seems like I have no other way than repeating the process of activating venv via Select Interpreter everytime i restart VScode. is there a more convenient way or a way to change VScode terminal setting so i don't have to do this?

thanks.

i have these settings in settings.json currently

`{`

`"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,`
`"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "source/venv/bin/activate",`

`}`

Answer (score 2):

After you selected an environment for a project, the VSCode can remember it, although you have restarted the VSCode. You do not need to select the python interpreter again. So, I do not clearly know what you mean, the environment problem or the environment in the terminal problem.

But you can try to add this in the settings.json:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
```

And you can create a new terminal and activate the environment in the terminal through the shortcut of **Ctrl+Shift+`**